# mxgraph: Anchor cell drag along specific x/y value

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I need to anchor a newly draw cell to an existing cell's y value (draggable only along the X-axis). When dragging the existing cell, the newly created cell should update y-value along with this. Any ideas?